# Simpler expression for a certain determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

A question in elementary linear algebra, while considering the [Cayley-Menger Determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html):

> Given an $n\times n$ matrix $M$, consider $$\tilde{M}=\begin{pmatrix} M & (1,1,\cdots, 1)^\top \\  (1,1,\cdots, 1)& 0\end{pmatrix}$$ Is it possible to express $\det(\tilde{M})$ in terms of $\det(M)$ and some simpler terms?

You may assume that $M$ is symmetric. (This problem, in its original setting in my research, has the condition that $M$ is symmetric. But it'll be more interesting to solve the general case.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can certainly specialize the [determinant formula for block matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) to the *[bordering](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bordering_method)* case:

$$\begin{vmatrix}\mathbf M&\mathbf e\\\mathbf e^\top&0\end{vmatrix}=-(\mathbf e^\top\mathbf M^{-1}\mathbf e)\det\mathbf M$$

where $\mathbf e$ is the column vector whose entries are all $1$'s.

Comment: Oh I didn't know such a formula. This is amazing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Block matrix manipulation isn't exactly common knowledge these days...

Comment: Look up the Schur complement of a matrix.

Comment: @copper, yes, that's another way of looking at this. :)

Comment: @J.M. Was that... a sarcasm? I'm sorry if I was asking trivial questions.

Comment: @progressive, not at all. Do what copper.hat said; you should also look into Schur complements.

Comment: Of course that formula only works if $M$ is invertible.